# return false on a href onclick still calls the link when I load it with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this link created by an ajax call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" data-accordion="accordion-content bg-highlight accordion-head-href">
    My Name
    <i class="accordion-icon-right fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Even if I added the `return false` code, the `#` link is still called (the page is reloaded).

I create the link with this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'my-example-url',
    success:function(data) {
        // data.html CONTAINS THE LINK
        if (data.html) {
            $('.my-div-class').append(data.html);
        }
    },
    error: function(data) { console.log(data) }
});
```

Comment: Since the anchor is set with `href="#"` the page shouldnt reload at all are you sure that link is causing the reload and not some other part of your code or some third party library

Comment: Just use `href="#/"` instead of `href="#"`. Or you can write `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: @SudhirOjha What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @PatrickEvans thats why I am trying to use "return false", to avoid third party library

Comment: By reload do you mean the url in the address bar gets a trailing `#`? If so the page hasnt actually reloaded, the hash just changed. And by third party code i meant that some code else where that you included in the page isnt the issue (eg jquery bootstrap etc)

Comment: @PatrickEvans the page is reloaded with # in the url (its actually reloaed)

Comment: Then some other code is causing it as mentioned an anchor with `href="#"` natively just sets the hash it wouldnt do a full page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the href attribute as href="javascript:;"

Or call javascript function on onclick event and use event.preventDefault()

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault();})(event)">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" data-accordion="accordion-content bg-highlight accordion-head-href">
My Name
    <i class="accordion-icon-right fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

Comment: Same result. The page is reloaded with "#" anchor